# cell.accessoryType with search bar don't affect with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, nspredicate, accessorytype

I've made a view for editing friends with search bar. Everything works fine, but when I find users with search bar, cell.accessoryType isn't right. (My cell.accessoryType is good when I don't use search bar).
Checkmark isn't for the right user.

I think it's a problem in "isFriend" action ?

Here is my code :

editfriends.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface EditFriendsViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>


@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *allUsers;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFUser *currentUser;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *friends;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *searchResults;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFUser *user;


@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *MindleNav;



-(BOOL)isFriend:(PFUser*)user;

@end
```

editfriends.m :

```
#import "EditFriendsViewController.h"

@interface EditFriendsViewController ()

@end

@implementation EditFriendsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.MindleNav];

    self.searchResults = [[NSArray alloc] init];


    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query orderByAscending:@"email"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
        else {
            self.allUsers = objects;
            //            self.user = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
            [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        }
    }];

    self.currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [self.searchResults count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [self.allUsers count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    PFUser *user = [self.allUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] email];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = user.email;
    }


    if ([self isFriend:user]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    PFRelation *friendsRelation = [self.currentUser relationforKey:@"friendsRelation"];

    //Edit Friends with searchbar
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        PFUser *user = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if ([self isFriend:user]) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;


            for(PFUser *friend in self.searchResults) {
                if ([friend.objectId isEqualToString:user.objectId]) {
                    [self.friends removeObject:friend];
                                [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
                    break;
                }
            }

            [friendsRelation removeObject:user];
        }
        else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            [self.friends addObject:user];
            [friendsRelation addObject:user];
            [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        }

        [self.currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
        }];

        //Edit Friends
    } else {
        PFUser *user = [self.allUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if ([self isFriend:user ]) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

            for(PFUser *friend in self.friends) {
                if ([friend.objectId isEqualToString:user.objectId]) {
                    [self.friends removeObject:friend];
                    break;
                }
            }

            [friendsRelation removeObject:user];
        }
        else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            [self.friends addObject:user];
            [friendsRelation addObject:user];
        }

        [self.currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
        }];
    }


}

#pragma mark - Helper methods
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"email beginswith[c] %@", searchText];
    self.searchResults = [self.allUsers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)isFriend:(PFUser *)user {
    for(PFUser *friend in self.friends) {
        if ([friend.objectId isEqualToString:user.objectId]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear to be because you're using the wrong user object to check the status. Compare with:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSArray *sourceData = (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView ? self.searchResults : self.allUsers);
    PFUser *user = [sourceData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = user.email;

    if ([self isFriend:user]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Wouawh... Just PERFECT ! And that compress well the code :)

Comment: You can use the same form later too: `cell.accessoryType = ([self isFriend:user] ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)` but when using this form be sure that your code doesn't loose readability...

Comment: Yes, that's great ! I didn't know this type of code :)

Comment: The predicate, yes, probably. So `username` and `email` should work. Note that there are other `NSArray` methods for filtering, like `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:`.

Comment: Thanks ! And do you know how to affect name of PFUser (in my Parse database) and not user.email ? I've try NSString *name = [[self.friends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"]; cell.textLabel.text = name; my NSPredicate works with : [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText]; Is it because user.email is recognized and not user.name ? Error Xcode : -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]

Comment: Yes my predicate works now, but when I want to display user name in edit friends, my app crashes : -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]
I think the problem is NSString *name = [[self.friends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
cell.textLabel.text = name;

Comment: The error would suggest that you are using the wrong array of objects again, so you expect the count to be X and it is actually Y

Comment: Oh shiiiit ! I didn't see ! That works better with the other array ... I'm really sorry :)